# Can GUI scaling be controlled on a JFrame by JFrame basis?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have an application where I need to allow automatic scaling for some frames (-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true) and disabled for others (-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false).

Is there any way I can control scaling behaviour at run time from within the application when I construct/launch the JFrame?

Comment: I'm guessing that usage of [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: No. The issue that I have is that I am using an OpenGL library that I cannot change. When Microsoft Windows scaling is applied (say 150%)  the JFrame increases by 150% but the GL canvas stays the same size. So I end up with a grey border on two sides of the of the canvas inside the frame. By turning uiScaling=false stops this. However, this also disables scaling when moving the non OpenGL GUI’s between screens with different resolutions. So what I would like to be able to do is disable scaling for the OpenGL JFrames and enable for everything else. This is an issue in Java 14 (not 1.8).